# Invoke prepareRenderer of JTable Swing

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Have my implementation of `JTable` with modify prepareRenderer.

```
public class MyTable extends JTable {

    private List<Client> list;

    public MyTable(TableModel model){
        super(model);
        if (model instanceof ProfitAbilityTableModel){
            list=((ProfitAbilityTableModel)model).getClients();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int vColIndex){
        Component rComp=super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        if(list!=null){
            Client client=list.get(rowIndex);
            if(client.getExpected()==client.getReceived())
                rComp.setBackground(new Color(139, 255, 182));
            else
                rComp.setBackground(new Color(255,139,147));
        }

        return rComp;
    }
}
```

ProfitAbilityTableModel

```
public class ProfitAbilityTableModel  extends AbstractTableModel{

    private String []columnNames={"Имя учетной записи", "Ф.И.О. Клиента","Адрес",
            "Получено грн.", "Предпологалось грн."};
    private List<Client> clients;

    public ProfitAbilityTableModel(List<Client> clients){
        this.clients=clients;
    }

    public ProfitAbilityTableModel(){};

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return (clients!=null) ? clients.size(): 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
        Client client=clients.get(r);
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                return client.getUserName();
            case 1:
                return client.getName() +" " + client.getSurname() + " " + client.getPatronymic();
            case 2:
                return client.getAddress();
            case 3:
                return client.getReceived();
            case 4:
                return client.getExpected();    
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int c){
        return columnNames[c];
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }


}
```

In mainFrame create table with empty tableModel
table = new MyTable(new ProfitAbilityTableModel());

when press button do this

```
button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                table.setModel(new ProfitAbilityTableModel(ClientFactory.getClients(10)));
            }
        });
```

where ClientFactory:

```
public class ClientFactory {
    public static List<Client> getClients(int amount){
        List<Client> result=new ArrayList<>();
        Client c;
        int received,expected;
        for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){
            c=new Client();
            c.setUserName("username " + i);
            c.setName("name "+ i);
            c.setSurname("surname " + i);
            c.setPatronymic("patronymic" + i);
            c.setAddress("address " + i);
            expected=(int)(Math.random()*100);
            received=(int)(Math.random()*100);
            if(received>expected)
                received=expected;
            c.setExpected(expected);
            c.setReceived(received);
            result.add(c);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Made this for change color of row if two fields of `Client` are equals.
It's work fine when create `MyTable`, but when change tableModel all row has default background color (white). How invoke this code when change table model?

Comment: Yes, when press button program set new table model with new data. It's tricky.In future it's take data from DB

Comment: Maybe i go in wrong way? So told me, how to realize it correct.

Comment: 1. `set new table model with new data. It's tricky.` - don't see there any advantage, JTable and its XxxTableModel is designated to be re_usable, 2. have to look at (best of code and simple, clear logics inside ...) blog by @camickr [XxxTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=list+model) and [prepareRenderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=preparerenderer) most of code here about is only copy_paste from this blog, 3. `In future it's take data from DB` search here for Table from database too

Comment: 1. convert index to model, then you to test for value in model from column 6th (`if(client.getExpected()==client.getReceived())` make me as nonsence, this item must to returns real value - `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean`), 2. remove recrusive testing for `if(list!=null)`{ should be `model isn't mull`, better to test if number of rows in model is greather than 0 (must be for prepareRenderer as default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by add to ProfitAbilityTableModel  this methods:

```
public void setData(List<Client> clients){
        this.clients=clients;
    }

    public Client getClient(int index){
        return clients.get(index);
    }
```

Change my table:

```
public class MyTable extends JTable {

    public MyTable(TableModel model){
        super(model);   
    }
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int vColIndex){
        Component rComp=super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
        if(getModel()!=null){
            Client client=((ProfitAbilityTableModel)getModel()).getClient(rowIndex);
            if(client.getExpected()==client.getReceived())
                rComp.setBackground(new Color(139, 255, 182));
            else
                rComp.setBackground(new Color(255,139,147));
        }

        return rComp;
    }
}
```

In main frame update data by button like this:

```
ProfitAbilityTableModel model=(ProfitAbilityTableModel)table.getModel();
model.setData(ClientFactory.getClients(10));
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: post an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable / XxxTableModel stored in local variable, never to call model.fireXxxXxx out of the models class, again your model isn't completed, this way is road to troubles, code for JTable, its model and renderer is very simple job, stop complicating the simple things and incorectly